# Kext signing for Mac using script file

Tags: macos, kernel-extension

How to sign Kext in Mac using a script file instead of using Xcode for signing? What is the command used to Sign Kext? 
Will the Kext signed in Mavericks work on Yosemite?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [codesign](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html) command to sign from a script and yes, signing from Mavericks will work on Yosemite.

If you haven't already done so, you will need ensure that you have requested the Kext signing attribute from Apple for your DeveloperID.

Comment: I had requested for Kext signing attribute from Apple for my Developer ID and i got it.I followed the steps given in the link.When i tried to sign the kext using codesign command i got the error "Developer ID Application: **** (XD*****): no identity found"

Comment: Can you show the full command that you're using to sign the kext?

Comment: codesign -s "Developer ID Application: my_company_id (X*******)" mykext.kext/

Comment: Don't add the code in brackets, so that would be: codesign -s "Developer ID Application: my_company_id" mykext.kext/

Comment: If you've not got any typo errors, then you could try setting the private key to allow access to all applications, just to test it. I definitely sign it without the (X******) section. Also, are you running the codesign from a command line, or using a script via something like Jenkins? If the certificate is in one user's keychain, but you're calling codesign from another, it won't find the certificate.

Comment: I am running the codesign from terminal.Yep i tried giving permissions to private key for all applications.But still this error is breaking my head.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66463/discussion-between-merlin069-and-ashok).

Answer (score 0):

When i tried to sign the Kext as a root user i got this issue but if Iam trying to sign using mac user account Iam able to sign Kext successfully.